# Java7 installation in Linux

Tags: linux, java-7, redhat

I have downloaded and installed Java 7 from tarball.I changed the JAVA_HOME path in .profile.
The problem is that when I am doing a java -version check, the Linux is detecting java 1.6.
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Linux typically has bash shell as default shell, you can update .bashrc file in  home directory with PATH pointing to javahome/bin folder for java executable to be in the path.

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin/

Note: This shall make other executables of this version of java  like jar, javac, javadoc, to be available. 
If this is not preferred, create a soft link using "ln" command pointing to your javahome/bin/java